# Error trying to base64 secret in GitHub actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, base64, github-actions

I am trying to `base64` encode a `json` gcp service account in a github actions step as follows

```
    - name: base64 encode the gcr sa
      id: base64-encode
      run:
        echo "::set-output name=STAGING_GCR_SA_BASE64::$(echo -n ${{ secrets.GCR_SA }} | base64)"
```

The step fails as follows:

```
sh: command substitution: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `***'
```

I assume this is because there is no way to manipulate secrets?

Is there a way around this? (apart from storing the secret directly as `base64`)

Comment: It might be because of special characters in the secret; try `echo -n '${{ secrets.GCR_SA }}'`.

Comment: It's also strange that the error says `sh` and not `bash`, are you setting a different default shell somewhere?

Comment: No I am not explicitly setting any shell tbh

Comment: "I assume this is because there is no way to manipulate secrets?" - There is nothing in actions that would prevent you from manipulating secrets. They're only masked before being written to the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I could get your approach to work if I disable the base64 line wrapping using `-w 0`.

Since you posted your question `set-output` has been [deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) and the syntax for setting GHA outputs has changed, so it'd look like this:

`echo "{STAGING_GCR_SA_BASE64}=$(echo -n ${{ secrets.GCR_SA }} | base64 -w 0)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`